# How to specify the order in which a rich:extendedDataTable selection and h:selectOneMenu value are applied

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I'm working on an application that's basically a customised database administration tool.

The page structure is basically the following:

```
<a4j:region>
  <h:selectOneMenu value='#{bean.selectedTable}'>
    ...
     <a4j:ajax event='change' render='tablePanel'/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <a4j:outputPanel id='tablePanel'>
    <rich:extendedDataTable id='table' selection='#{bean.selectedRows}' ...>
      <f:facet name='header'>
        [datascroller etc.]
        <a4j:commandButton action='#{bean.deleteSelectedRows}' execute='@region' render='tablePanel'/>
      </f:facet>
      [columns]
    </rich:extendedDataTable>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
<a4j:region>
```

The selectOneMenu is used to choose which database table will be displayed. The backing bean is request scoped and set up to pick the first available table as a default when it's initialised. I'm using an ExtendedDataTable subclass to paginate data in the database.

When I click the commandButton to delete the rows, it seems that the extendedDataTable component determines the selected rows /before/ the value of bean.selectedTable is applied. This means that no matter what table is selected in the dropdown menu, RichFaces tells me the selected rows are some (more or less arbitrary) rows in the default database table.

I verified that this is an ordering problem, when deleteSelectedRows() is called the value of selectedTable is correct. I'm using Richfaces 4 M6, and a4j:keepAlive doesn't seem to be there anymore to preserve the bean state.

Is there a way to tell RichFaces / JSF in which order to do these things? I tried using immediate="true" on the h:selectOneMenu but that didn't help.

Also, after a delete, the tablePanel doesn't seem to be rerendered, while another a4j:commandButton that adds new records with the same execute and render attributes seems to work fine. Is there a way to debug the state of RichFaces ajax requests / hook into them via events?

Comment: I don't know RichFaces too well, but are you sure '@region' is correct value for execute? Maybe try adding id to <a4j:region> tag and select this id in execute attribute instead of @region?

Comment: I've mentioned that the value of bean.selectedTable does get applied during the AJAX request, so the region specification _should_ be correct - the select component gets executed. It just seems to happen after the table component determines the selection.

Comment: A workaround I'm using so far is declaring a `@PostConstruct` method on the backing bean and looking for the value of the selectOneMenu there to set it before any RichFaces processing. I'm not particularly happy about the hack and would still be interested in knowing if there's a clean solution.